# How do I properly work with two or more buttons having the same name?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a form with custom design, tabs and buttons with the same name.
That is, buttons placed in different tabs and have the name "More ..."

However, each button has different ajax-callback function.

```
   $form['btn_services_geo_add_more_wrapper']['btn_services_geo_add_more'] = [
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' =>  $this->t('More ...'),
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [$this, 'servicesGeoAddMore'],
            'event' => 'mouseup',
            'progress' => [
                'type' => 'none',
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $form['btn_services_by_place_add_more_wrapper']['btn_services_by_place_add_more'] = [
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' =>  $this->t('More ...'),
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [$this, 'servicesByPlaceAddMore'],
            'event' => 'mouseup',
            'progress' => [
                'type' => 'none',
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

When debugging I noticed that weird errors had been appeared. But when I changed the name of one of buttons to "More 1 ...", these errors ceased to occur.

Could you clarify me, how to work with several buttons having the same name ? I tried to set the id property, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't work with 2 buttons that have the same name and value, in submission it would be impossible to tell them apart.

You need to set a unique name for each button; that will allow Drupal to distinguish which one was clicked and should be actioned.

```
$form['btn_services_geo_add_more_wrapper']['btn_services_geo_add_more'] = [
  ...
  '#name' => 'more_1',
];



$form['btn_services_by_place_add_more_wrapper']['btn_services_by_place_add_more'] = [
  ...
  '#name' => 'more_2'
];
```

Comment: I have tested the way with two different #name properties.
Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving them unique name through #attribute instead of changing the #value.

```
    $form['btn_services_geo_add_more_wrapper']['btn_services_geo_add_more'] = [
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' =>  $this->t('More ...'),
        '#attributes' => array('name' => 'more1'),//
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [$this, 'servicesGeoAddMore'],
            'event' => 'mouseup',
            'progress' => [
                'type' => 'none',
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $form['btn_services_by_place_add_more_wrapper']['btn_services_by_place_add_more'] = [
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' =>  $this->t('More ...'),
        '#attributes' => array('name' => 'more2'),
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [$this, 'servicesByPlaceAddMore'],
            'event' => 'mouseup',
            'progress' => [
                'type' => 'none',
            ]
        ]
    ];
```